# error: redefinition of 'get_pointer'T* get_pointer(T* p) c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

error: redefinition of 'get_pointer'T* get_pointer(T* p)

[I am getting the error you see in the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUlNJ.png)

**//Itemshop_manager.h**

```
#pragma once


#include "stdafx.h" //error: 4th line

#ifdef ENABLE_ITEMSHOP_SYSTEM
class CItemShopManager : public singleton<CItemShopManager>
{
public:
    CItemShopManager();
    ~CItemShopManager();
    
    void                        Initialize();
    void                        LoadItems(BYTE bType, DWORD dwCount, TItemShopItem * pItems);
    void                        LoadEditors(DWORD dwCount, TItemShopEditor* pEditors);
    TItemShopItem               FindItemByID(DWORD id, DWORD category);
    void                        OpenItemShop(LPCHARACTER ch);
    void                        BuyItem(LPCHARACTER ch, DWORD id, DWORD category);
    void                        DeleteItem(LPCHARACTER ch, DWORD id, DWORD category, bool deleteFromDB = true);
    void                        AddItem(LPCHARACTER ch, DWORD vnum, DWORD count, DWORD price, DWORD category);
    void                        EditItem(LPCHARACTER ch, DWORD vnum, DWORD count, DWORD price, DWORD category, DWORD id);
private:
    std::vector<TItemShopItem>  m_vec_itemShopItems;
    std::set<LPCHARACTER>       m_set_pkCurrentViewer;
    std::vector<char*>          m_vec_pkEditors;
    void                        AddEditor(char* szName);
    bool                        IsEditor(LPCHARACTER ch);
    bool                        IsViewer(LPCHARACTER ch);
    void                        AddViewer(LPCHARACTER ch);
    void                        RemoveViewer(LPCHARACTER ch);
    void                        ViewerChatPacket(BYTE bType, const char * szChat);
};
#endif
```

**//cmd_general.cpp**

```
#ifdef ENABLE_ITEMSHOP_SYSTEM
#include "itemshop_manager.h"//error: line 52
#endif
```

**//Itemshop_manager.cpp**

```
#ifdef ENABLE_ITEMSHOP_SYSTEM
#include "itemshop_manager.h"//error: 8th line
```

**Thank you for your help.**

**stdafx.h**

```
template<typename T>
T* get_pointer(T* p)
{
    return p;
}
```

Comment: You even did not show where the function  get_pointer is defined.

Comment: And this is not a C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `#pragma once` (or [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard#Use_of_#include_guards)) from stdafx.h. Possibly stdafx.h is included - directly or indirectly - more than once from one .cpp.

If however you intend to use stdafx.h as [PCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files?view=vs-2019), then `#pragma once` is not needed but stdafx.h should only be included from .cpp, not from any header.